# Как поместить значение из lineEdit в переменную?

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, сигналы-слоты, sql-injection

У меня возникла проблема, как мне передать значение из поля `lineEdit` в переменную, чтобы это значение вывелось в консоль с помощью **`print`**.

Вот изначальный код из *Qt Designer*:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(390, 154)
    MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(17, 23, 18);")
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
    self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 110, 75, 23))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(14)
    font.setBold(True)
    font.setWeight(75)
    self.pushButton.setFont(font)
    self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 
    255);\n"
    "border-radius: 30;")
    self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
    self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
    self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 211, 41))
    font = QtGui.QFont()
    font.setPointSize(12)
    self.label.setFont(font)
    self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(92, 110, 148);")
    self.label.setObjectName("label")
    self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 113, 41))
    self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(5, 9, 18);\n"
    "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
    "font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
    self.lineEdit.setText("")
    self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
    self.statusbar.setStyleSheet("")
    self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
    MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
    self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОК"))
    self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите время (в 
    секундах):"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

А вот код из файла где я пытался прописывать логику приложения:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget,
QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox)
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from Shutdown import Ui_MainWindow
import os
#1
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
#2
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
MainWindow.show()
#3

#4
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создайте другой класс, который наследуется от соответствующего виджета,
и используйте созданный класс для его заполнения формой,
созданной в  *Qt Designer*.

Чтобы узнать больше о виджете `QLineEdit` - почитайте 
https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#editingFinished

```
import sys
#import os
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
#from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot
#from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QMainWindow, QApplication, QWidget,
#    QPushButton, QAction, QLineEdit, QMessageBox)

#from Shutdown import Ui_MainWindow
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(390, 154)
        MainWindow.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(17, 23, 18);")
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setStyleSheet("")
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(160, 110, 75, 23))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        font.setBold(True)
        font.setWeight(75)
        self.pushButton.setFont(font)
        self.pushButton.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
        "border-radius: 30;")
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 211, 41))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(92, 110, 148);")
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(230, 50, 113, 41))
        self.lineEdit.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(5, 9, 18);\n"
        "color: rgb(255, 255, 255);\n"
        "font: 75 12pt \"MS Shell Dlg 2\";")
        self.lineEdit.setText("")
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setStyleSheet("")
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "ОК"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Введите время (в секундах):"))


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        # тут ваша  логика
        
        validador = QtCore.QRegExp("[0-9]*")
        ok = QtGui.QRegExpValidator(validador, self)
        self.lineEdit.setValidator(ok)
        self.lineEdit.setFocus()
        
        # нажмите на кнопку чтобы получить значение из поля LineEdit на печать
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.print_lineEdit)
        # или нажмите клавиши Return или Enter
        self.lineEdit.editingFinished.connect(self.print_lineEdit)
        
    def print_lineEdit(self):
        text = self.lineEdit.text()                     # значение из поля LineEdit
        print(f'Значение из lineEdit на печать: {text}') 
    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Спасибо большое!Нужно будет в этом разобраться!Я всего лишь несколько дней пытаюсь пользоваться pytQ5 и многое ещё не понимаю!

Comment: @SashaGulyaev пожалуйста